# How to run a .py file using Crontab in Terminal?

Tags: cron

I have a python code which must run every hour.

I set Crontab to be:

> 0 * * * * python /Users.../file.py

Will it actually run the python code? Or Crontab can only do things like 'echo' etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can run the python code from Crontab here is an example that I use:

First, to open crontab file:

```
crontab -e
```

On the last line of crontab file I write the command:

```
0 */4 * * * python3 /home/integrations/geckoboard/diario1.0.py
```

Where integrations is my User, geckoboard my folder and diario1.0.py is the code I want to run

With that my pythonfile will run every 4 hours.